# An explanation of El Shadai, please!

Tags: genesis, word-study, textual-criticism, names-of-god, divine-counsel

Does the Biblical term, El Shadai, mean mountaintop god, or perhaps, The Many Breasted God? I have seen both answers presented as truth claims!

> Gen 17:1 (NLT) - When Abram was ninety-nine years old, the LORD
> appeared to him and said, “I am **El-Shaddai—‘God Almighty.’** Serve
> me faithfully and live a blameless life.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would give us the source of the claims that El Shadai could mean "mountaintop god" or "the many breasted god".

Comment: I sure wish I had specific sources for these explanations of the deity mosses went to visit on Mount Hebron! Wikipedia, or similar, is my thought, but I have viewed many,many, Jewish reference pages online, also! I will dig into this soon!

Comment: The thought of, a many breasted god, appears to be a god whom provides for his clan!

Answer (score 2):

The name "El-Shaddai" consists of two parts

- "El" is an abbreviation of Elohim, meaning "God"
- "Shaddai" means (from BDB) "Almighty" see Gen 49:25, Num 24:16, Ruth 1:20, 21, Job 5:17, 6:14, 8:3, 11:7, 13:3, 21:15, 20, 22:23, 25, 26, 23:16, 24:1, 27:2, 10, 11, etc.

Thus, this title is simply God-Almighty as per, Gen 17:1, 28:3, 35:11, 43:14, 48:3, 49:25, Ex 6:3, etc.  That is, this title is used to describe the omnipotence of the LORD God.

Ellicott says this about Gen 17:1 -

> **El Shaddai**. The word is Archaic, but there is no doubt that it means strong so as to overpower. Besides its use in Genesis we find it
> employed as the name of Deity by Balaam (Numbers 24:4; Numbers 24:16);
> by Naomi (Ruth 1:20); and in the Book of Job, where it occurs
> thirty-one times.

Answer (score 2):

### Options

Concerning the name, אֵ֣ל שַׁדַּ֔י, the BHQ gives the following commentary:

> 17:1  אֵ֣ל שַׁדַּ֔י The etymology and meaning of ‏אל שדי‎ has been a
> matter of dispute from the very beginning of biblical exegesis (on the
> many attempts, see Westermann, Genesis, 2:255–56). Ancient Jewish
> exegesis divides ‏שדי into two parts, ש-די, the latter meaning
> “enough” (Gen. Rab. 46:3, which quotes Aquila’s translation ἱκανός).
> This may be the tradition according to which G translates שדי as
> ἱκανός in some passages (Ruth 1:20, 21; Job 21:15; 31:2; etc.). This
> is also Rashi’s interpretation of the present passage. In the same
> spirit, several manuscripts of TSmr render the word as ספוקה, “the
> provider” (Tal, “Samaritan Targum,” 214–15; DSA, 606). An ancient
> etymology associates the word with the root šdd, “strength,”
> producing the rendering omnipotens of V, as well as the explanation
> given by medieval exegetes: “strong” (Ibn Ezra, Qimḥi). In many
> cases, G does not translate שדי. Instead, the translator uses a
> pronoun whose form depends on the speaker. In the present passage it
> is the first person singular, as it is in 28:3; 43:14; 48:3; and
> 49:25. In 35:11 the second person pronoun appears, according to the
> context. See Wevers, Notes on Genesis, 229; Rösel, “Übersetzung der
> Gottesnamen,” 373–74.

This is, perhaps, both the best and shortest commentary that one could hope for.

We note that the etymology of the word has been debated from the very beginning.

As options for meaning the BHQ commentary gives us:

- ⲓⲕⲁⲛⲟⲥ = sufficient
- omnipotens (Vulgate)
- Strong

So, where does this idea of breasts come into play?  Hamilton gives us this commentary:

> The one who gives this directive to Abram is El Shaddai. This divine
> name appears forty-eight times in the OT, most often in Job (31)
> times, but without the accompanying “El”). On the basis of the LXX
> translation of this term in Job (always pantokrátōr) and the most
> frequent Vulg. translation (omnipotens), many modern versions render
> El Shaddai as “God Almighty.” There have been several attempts to
> ascertain the etymology of Shaddai. An ancient suggestion sees in
> šadday the relative particle šᵉ and the adjective day, “sufficient,”
> thus, “he who is sufficient.” This is reflected in Aquila and Symm.
> (hikanós).   A second suggestion links Shaddai with the verb
> šāḏaḏ, “to destroy, overpower”; thus “he who destroys,
> overpowers.” This etymology is surely the source of LXX pantokrátōr.
> It is also suggested by the wordplay in Isa. 13:6, “the day of the
> Lord is near; as destruction from Shaddai [šōḏ miššadday] it will
> come.”    Some proposals have geographical features. One connects
> šadday with śāḏeh, “El of the plain (or the fields, the steppe).”7
> Another connects it with a Semitic root ṯdw/y, whose original meaning
> was “breast” but which later evolved into “mountain.”8 Thus El Shaddai
> is “El of the mountain” or “the mountain one.” A third, more recent
> attempt links El Shaddai with bêl sadê, the most common title given
> to the god Amurru in early Babylonian texts.9 For bêl sadê the most
> accurate meaning is “Lord of the steppe,” and if the connection with
> Heb. šadday is sustained, then El Shaddai is “El of the steppe.”10
>
> (Victor P. Hamilton, The Book of Genesis, Chapters 1–17, New
> International Commentary on the Old Testament. Accordance electronic
> ed. (Grand Rapids: Eerdmans, 1990), 462-463.)

Evidently, the so-called "breasts" definition comes a repointing of the word. Cf BDB:

> 7699  † [שַׁד] n. m. Ho 9:14 female breast;—abs. ‏שָׁ֑ד‎ La 4:3;
> elsewhere du. ‏שָׁדַיִם‎ Ho 9:14 +, cstr. ‏שְׁדֵי‎ Ez 23:21 +, sf.
> ‏שָׁדַי‎ Ct 1:13, 8:10, ‏שָׁדַיִךְ 4:5 +, etc.;—breast:
>
> (BDB, s.v. “שׁדה,” 994.)

The inclusion of the yod at the end would then make the word a construct.

### Possibilities for proper meaning

How one translates the word largely depends on one's view of the overall coherence of the bible (hence, a hermeneutical decision).

Those who have a high view of the bible take the words as they are used in context throughout the Tanack, concluding that the books within the Hebrew canon have a precedence over those outside the bible.

Those who have a low view of the bible's inspiration and integrity look to how the word is used *outside* of the bible, concluding that extrabiblical usage is more authoritative.

### Probabilities for proper meaning

Even if one did not conclude that the bible had much internal coherence, concluding that שַׁד, "breasts" is the meaning has exceedingly little evidence.

Having said that, though, that does not help us pin down with certainty what the word precisely means.  Look at the wide variance in the Versions for this verse:

- “καὶ ὤφθη κύριος τῷ Αβραμ καὶ εἶπεν αὐτῷ Ἐγώ εἰμι ὁ θεός σου·” (Genesis 17:1 LXX1) (The LXX translates the name as "your God" with no added description)
- “et dixit illi, Ego sum Deus.” (Genesis 17:1 V-LATINA)  (The VL follows the LXX here)
- “dixitque ad eum ego Deus omnipotens” (Genesis 17:1 VULG-T) (Jerome takes a stab and concludes that it is a name referring to God's omnipotence)
- ”ܘܐܡ݂ܪ ܠܗ. ܐܢܐ ܐܢܐ ܐܠܫܕܝ ܐܠܗܐ.“ (Genesis 17:1 PESHOT-T) (The Syriac takes a somewhat fascinating choice: "And he said to him, I, I, El-Shadai [am] God."  Evidently, they were so reverent and cautious, they didn't even dare to translate it.  There are many other examples, when it comes to other names of God, that they have no hesitation to go in a more functional direction. This too makes us wonder about the lexical certainty of the word)

With all of this in mind, it would be wise to be cautious both in arriving at an all-too-cavalier conclusion as to the meaning. Likewise, some leniency should be granted to English translations, who, at the end of the day, have to actually decide to print a word on the page as a translation.

### A concluding cautious assertion

The word doesn't appear too much in the OT. But there are a couple of places where its usage might help:

- ”וָאֵרָ֗א אֶל־אַבְרָהָ֛ם אֶל־יִצְחָ֥ק וְאֶֽל־יַעֲקֹ֖ב בְּאֵ֣ל שַׁדָּ֑י וּשְׁמִ֣י יְהוָ֔ה לֹ֥א נוֹדַ֖עְתִּי לָהֶֽם׃“ (Exodus 6:3 HMT-W4)

In Exodus 6 there seems to be a connection between this name and the tetragrammaton.

Another useful passage is outside of the Torah:

- ”וְקוֹל֙ כַּנְפֵ֣י הַכְּרוּבִ֔ים נִשְׁמַ֕ע עַד־הֶחָצֵ֖ר הַחִיצֹנָ֑ה כְּק֥וֹל אֵל־שַׁדַּ֖י בְּדַבְּרֽוֹ׃“ (Ezekiel 10:5 HMT-W4)

Here we have the vision of the Lord's might and splendor.

There are other passages one could make use of. But this should be at least enough here that the passages refer to the Lord in a rarer, more special way. they give emphasis to the Lord's aseity and splendor.  While we can clearly say that "breasts" is the least likely option, pressing it too far, saying that "ⲡⲁⲛⲧⲟⲕⲣⲁⲧⲱⲣ" is the only option would be too far as well.

Comment: Love this and really appreciate you assisting growth in my hermeneutic surrounding the passages about El Shadai! Guess it's just best to listen to Amy Grant sing her pretty tune, about this fascinating character of the ancient texts, and chill some! Thats what I ultimately have decided to do! It's not worth stressing about biblical minutia! Again thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most Hebrew commentators assume the key word is **"Dai" - "די"** which means enough, sufficient.  "Sh" just means that/which.

For example, [Rashi in Genesis](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.17.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=endata-ref=%22Rashi%20on%20Genesis%2017:1:1%22) quotes the midrash which says that G-d is describing Himself as One whose Godship suffices for all living beings.  (No other gods necessary)

Another example is a discussion the [Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.12a.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en&id=AW-698744211/R4bsCJbexNoDEJP7l80C) where Reish Lakish says G-d said "Dai!" to tell the world when to stop expanding

Answer (score 0):

Shaddai as a female deity is suggested by the fact that the word for "breast" is the first syllable of Shaddai and Canaanite mythology speaks of [twin mountains](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Myth/CanaaniteMythology) as holding up the heavens.

As other answers have mentioned, "el" means "god," both in Hebrew and various Canaanite languages. The primary supreme deity of Canaan was called simply "El" often with various epithets such as elyon (on high) or shaddai. Whether these were always merely descriptors of El or also the names of lesser deities is not known. In Jewish and Christian tradition he is God Almighty, the supreme and only deity who manifested in power to His people from Mount Sinai.

The idea that El Shaddai was a [female deity](https://healthylivingacademy.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Shaddai-meaning-fertility.pdf) is based on the fact that word שַׁד (shad) means breast (Strong's 7699). The Akkadian *shadû* (mountain) accounts for the association with mountains and possibly breasts as well. In Canaanite mythology, the twin mountains Targhizizi and Tharumagi held the heavenly firmament up above primordial ocean. However, the hypothesis that Shaddai was "She of the Breast/s" is based on linguistics and has no known basis in surviving Canaanite or Mesopotamian literature. El as the supreme male deity of the Canaanite pantheon, however, is well-attested. Finally it should be mentioned that a deity with a practically identical name, *bel sad-e*, 'lord of the mountain' is known as alternative way of referring to the [Amorite high god](https://www.crystalinks.com/amorites.html) Amurru.

Shaddai can also mean 'power' (the traditional understanding) and is related as well to 'destruction' (Strong's 7703).

**Conclusion**: Shaddai is a title implying awesome power applied to the Canaanite high god El and adopted as a way of referring to the God of Israel -"God Almighty." The hypothesis that Shaddai could refer to a female deity is not completely out of the question, but it is speculative with no apparent basis in surviving written records.