# Are "Almighty God" and its variations a poor translation?

Tags: greek, hebrew, attributes-of-god

I do not speak any ancient languages. I have no relevant scholarly credentials. I do know how to read and use a dictionary. I have read the whole Bible.

When God is referred to as "God Almighty" or "Almighty God" in the English translation, it appears to be (almost?) always translated from the ancient Hebrew *El Shadai* or *Yaweh Tzehva'ot*, or from the ancient Greek *Pantokrator*.

After a couple of hours of poking around Wikipedia, Stack Exchange, Bible Hub's [interlinear translations](https://biblescan.com/searchstrongs.php?q=almighty)), and the Latin Vulgate, I feel pretty confident in the following:

*El* means God, but *Shadai* has an unknown meaning, possibly related to destruction.

*Yaweh Tzehva'ot* is apparently unambiguously The Lord of Hosts/Armies.

The Septuagint, the ancient Greek translation of the 1st Testament (usually?) translates both ancient Hebrew names as Pantokrator. Pantokrator also appears in the original Greek of some Christian 2nd Testament books.

*Pantokrator* means *all-ruler*, that is, the one who has the highest authority. *Krator* appears to be unambiguously *ruler*. If my complete lack of any knowledge of ancient Greek is correct, *the all-mighty* should be something like *pantokratos* or *pantodunatos*.

It's only once you get to Latin that you get *Deus omnipotens* as a translation for *El Shadai* or *Pantokrator*.

Likewise the Nicene Creed: 325 at Nicaea? God is πατέρα παντοκράτορα, the father all-ruler. Likewise in 381 at Constantinople. 50-ish years later in the West? *Deum patrem omnipotentem*.

And hence "God the Father almighty" and "Dieu, le Père tout-puissant."

**Has the nuance of the meaning of these names and titles of God been lost in translation?** I would appreciate any instruction or correction.

---

Examples (emphasis mine):

2 Corinthians 6:16-18
New Revised Standard Version

> “I will live in them and walk among them,
> and I will be their God,
> and they shall be my people.
> Therefore come out from them,
> and be separate from them, says the Lord,
> and touch nothing unclean;
> then I will welcome you,
> and I will be your father,
> and you shall be my sons and daughters,
> says the **Lord Almighty**.”

Latin Vulgate

> Quoniam inhabitabo in illis, et inambulabo inter eos, et ero illorum Deus, et ipsi erunt mihi populus.
> Propter quod exite de medio eorum, et separamini, dicit Dominus, et immundum ne tetigeritis:
> et ego recipiam vos: et ero vobis in patrem, et vos eritis mihi in filios et filias, dicit **Dominus omnipotens**.

Greek

> Ἐνοικήσω ἐν αὐτοῖς καὶ ἐμπεριπατήσω*, καὶ ἔσομαι αὐτῶν Θεός, καὶ αὐτοὶ ἔσονταί μου λαός. διὸ ἐξέλθατε ἐκ μέσου αὐτῶν, καὶ ἀφορίσθητε, λέγει κύριος, καὶ ἀκαθάρτου μὴ ἅπτεσθε· κἀγὼ εἰσδέξομαι ὑμᾶς· καὶ ἔσομαι ὑμῖν εἰς πατέρα, καὶ ὑμεῖς ἔσεσθέ μοι εἰς υἱοὺς καὶ θυγατέρας, λέγει **κύριος παντοκράτωρ**.

Genesis 17 NRSV

> When Abram was ninety-nine years old, the Lord appeared to Abram, and said to him, “**I am God Almighty**; walk before me, and be blameless. And I will make my covenant between me and you, and will make you exceedingly numerous.”

Vulgate

> Postquam vero nonaginta et novem annorum esse coeperat, apparuit ei Dominus, dixitque ad eum: **Ego Deus omnipotens**: ambula coram me, et esto perfectus. Ponamque foedus meum inter me et te, et multiplicabo te vehementer nimis.

Anglicized Hebrew (via qbible.com)

> way'hiy av'räm Ben-Tish'iym shänäh w'tësha shäniym waYërä y'hwäh el-av'räm waYomer ëläyw **ániy-ël shaDay** hit'haLëkh' l'fänay weh'yëh tämiym

Comment: Please nominate a specific text or two to examine.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: @Dottard I have added a couple of representative texts in English, Latin, and as close to an original as I could get.

Comment: Have you checked the best lexicons which all agree that Shaddai means "almighty" which is very similar to "omnipotent" the latter means "all-powerful".  I am not sure what you problem is!!  You are also confusing two questions here about God-Almighty and LORD of Hosts/Armies.  These should be separate questions.

Comment: The wording of [Revelation 1:8](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/revelation/1-8.htm) is also relevant, in regard to Παντοκράτωρ.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you because this is a good question, but it has already been addressed here several times. [This is one example](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/90104/an-explanation-of-el-shadai-please) but you'll find others by searching for "Shaddai" in the search engine at the top of page. I am voting to close the q. as a duplicate but I do hope you will ask others. Just make sure to search key words or texts first.